# How do I automatically select the first panel in a declarative dojo wizard?

Tags: dojo, wizard

I have created a declarative dojo wizard in dojo 1.5 that is embedded in a dojo dialog like this:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="genWizardDialog" jsId="genWizardDialog" refreshOnShow="true" preventCache="true" title="Title">

<div dojoType="dojox.widget.Wizard" style='height: 375px; width:400px' hideDisabled="true" doneButtonLabel="someLabel">

<div id="wizard1" dojoType="dojox.widget.WizardPane" canGoBack="false" passFunction="panelOneDriver"></div>

<div id="wizard2" dojoType="dojox.widget.WizardPane" passFunction="validateBoxes" style="padding:8px; height:100%;"></div>
....I have some more panels. 

</div>
<!-- Here I have setup the cancel method. -->
<script type="dojo/method" event="cancelFunction">
     //dijit.byId("genWizardDialog").onSelected(0);         
     dijit.byId("genWizardDialog").hide();
</script>
</div>
```

Everything pretty much works. However, I have 4 panels. If I proceed to panel three and hit cancel. When I then click the button to start the dojo dialog I am already at panel 3! I want to start back at panel 1. As I have already invested time into the declarative approach I am hoping to avoid doing this programmatically. I found site that mentioned an onSelected() method to accomplish this -> http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/resetting-wizard-pane-and-contents-on-reopening-wizard-td158660.html, however, this didn't work and stands to reason since looking in the Wizard.js I don't see this method defined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pasted code, you have the cancelFunction event in the dialog's div, not the wizard's. So move the `<script>` tag inside the div that has `dojoType=dojox.widget.Wizard`.

To select a specific wizard pane, you can use the `selectChild` function.

```
<script type="dojo/method" event="cancelFunction">
    dijit.byId("genWizardDialog").hide();
    dijit.byId("genWizard").selectChild("wizard1", false);
</script>
```

In the above, I've assumed that your wizard has an id "genWizard", so you'd have to add that to the wizard's div.

Now the wizard will jump to the first wizard pane when you click its cancel button.

It will *not* jump to the first wizard pane if you just click the dialog's X button. If you want that too, you need to use the dialog's onHide event.

```
<script type="dojo/method" event="onHide">
    dijit.byId("genWizard").selectChild("wizard1", false);
</script>
```

This script tag has to be in the dialog's div, not the wizard's, make sure you get that right.

Comment: Hi Frode, Thx for the response. That did the trick. I actually just messed up the copy/paste of the cancelFunction, it was in the right place on my server just not in the above. But, your point was valid. Thx again.